# SendGrid not Preserving ActionMailer Template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, html-email, actionmailer, sendgrid

I have a Rails 4 app on Heroku that uses SendGrid. I created a mailer that shows a digest of a user's recent social media posts using Twitter's oEmbed API. The problem is, when I send the message and view it in my inbox, it's all plain text and the social media posts are missing. Not only that, but none of my styling is persisted.

What I would like to know is how to preserve the template generated by my mailer so that a user gets a nicely formatted HTML email.

Here are my current SendGrid seetings:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'heroku.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

I'll post the mailer code as well, but I don't know if it's relevant to the issue. All my other mailers are plain text messages.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "employers", media: "all" %>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="email">
                Hi <%= "#{@contact.first_name}" %>,
                <br /><br />
                We’re working hard to let everyone know what it’s like to work here at <%= @company.name %> – it’ll help us recruit smarter and faster.
                <br /><br />
                It would be amazing if you could share the following on social media – just click on the social media buttons!
                <br />
                <br style="clear:both" />
                <div class="results-label"><b>Recent Tweets</b></div>
                <% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
                    <%= @company.twitter_client.oembed(tweet, width: 550).html.html_safe %>
                <% end %>

                <div class="results-label"><b>Recent LinkedIn Posts</b></div>
                <div class="column-layout cols-1 search-results">
                    <div style="max-width: 640px;">
                        <% @linkedin_posts.each do |post| %>
                        <div class="card result-link">
                            <div class="content result result-post">
                                <div class="post-textarea">
                                    <div class="social">
                                        <div class="buttons">
                                            <a class="square-btn-med li" href="https://www.linkedin.com/nhome/updates?topic=<%= post.linkedin_id %>"><%= image_tag "icons-ebt.png" %></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="date-info">
                                        <%= "#{post.created_at.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").strftime("%a, %b %d, %Y")}  |  #{post.created_at.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").strftime("%l:%M %p %Z")}" %>
                                    </div>

                                    <br style="clear:both" />
                                    <div class="post"><%= "#{post.post}" %></div>
                                </div>
                                <% if post.attachment_url && post.media_url %>
                                <a class="square-btn-med li" href="https://www.linkedin.com/nhome/updates?topic=<%= post.linkedin_id %>">
                                    <div class="image-container social-media-post" style="background-image: url(<%= post.attachment_url %>)"></div>
                                </a>
                                <% elsif post.attachment_url && !post.media_url %>
                                <div class="image-container social-media-post" style="background-image: url(<%= post.attachment_url %>)"></div>
                                <% end %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <br style="clear:both" />
            <br />
            Thanks,
            <br />
            <%= @employer_name %>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the mailer code:

```
class PromotionMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: 'MyApp <info@myapp.com>'

    def new_promotion(contact, company, link, employer_name, employer_email)
        @contact = contact
        @company = company
        @link = link
        @subject = "Help us showcase #{@company.name}’s company culture!"
        @employer_name = employer_name
        mail(to: @contact.email, from: employer_email, subject: @subject)
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the mailer code? I suspect you may not be setting the content_type.

Comment: Just updated my question with the code. I ended up going a different route with this feature, but I'd still like to figure out why it wasn't working.

Comment: I don't see where you are setting the body. Please take a look at this: https://github.com/mikel/mail#writing-and-sending-a-multipartalternative-html-and-text-email